# Are "recipe requests" off-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I was wondering about the A&C version of "recipe requests" (something that is off-topic at [Seasoned Advice](http://cooking.stackexchange.com)). Would questions like this be off-topic?

- What can I do with all these pine cones in my front yard?
- I'm growing corn, what craft could I make with the husks and leaves after harvest?
- Is there a good holiday craft I can do with my second grade class inexpensively?

Comment: I think this is a dup of: http://meta.crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/43/how-do-we-deal-with-idea-generation-questions

Comment: Yeah. I think they're the same.

Comment: Geez, how did I not see that? Whoopsie.